# Trying to test a database connection without providing username/password credentials in Python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I would like to check if multiple Microsoft SQL databases are online by running a python script. I have found the pyodbc library but every example logs the user in when connecting. I just need a message or boolean telling me if the database is online.

Comment: What databases do you want to check?

Comment: Sorry They're Microsoft SQL as well as Maria DB

Comment: If the database is online and you pass bogus credentials then you should get an exception like "login failed" or "access denied". That's enough to tell you that it is indeed listening.